# GDB - Prevent disabling display

Tags: recursion, gdb

As title says, i get my display command disabled whenever gdb tries to print a value for a non reachable memory address.
Like this:

```
0x12345678 in My_function ()
1: x/8xb $r0
0x1:    Disabling display 1 to avoid infinite recursion.
warning: Got an error handling event: "Cannot access memory at address 0x1".
```

so on the next instruction i stop in, it will not automatically display r0 value, at least untill i input again

```
display /8xb $r0
```

command.
Is there a way to prevent gdb from disabling display even in the case that memory address is invalid?

Comment: did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no, i never found a way to do that :-/

Comment: @user69818 I was thinking about a workaround for this and, maybe, it could be done by defining a function that has both `display` and `nexti` (or whatever you need to step to desired instruction) commands inside of it: `define displayandnexti` <enter> `display /8xb $r0` <enter> `nexti` <enter> `end` <enter>. Since i do no longer work with this stuff, if you can, please test it and report here so i might add this as solution (probably the only one, if it works).